# MVC - Read data does not match the one in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have something weird happenning on my project.
I've got a table named Displacements.

[image]

I'm listing not Compensated Displacements in a grid:

[image]

However, whenever I do something, even refresh the page, this happens:
[image]

Strangely, the last Displacement gets one day shorter. I checked in the DB if something changed but no:
[image]

Sometimes it's doesn't even get the correct Start Date whenever I check the page with this grid. This error happens right after my query:

```
 public static List<Displacement> GetDisplacementsNotCompensatedByEmployeeID(Int32 employeeID) {
            List<Displacement> displacements = dataContext.Displacements.Where(dis => dis.Employee.IDEmployee == employeeID && dis.IsCompensated == false).ToList();
            return displacements;
        }
```

[image]

The StartDate should be 02-03-2015, not 03-03-2015. No, I don't change the date anywhere on the code. As you can see in the SQL Server DB screenshot. This is an MVC 5 project with  .NET Framework 4.5 and if I'm not wrong EF 6.1.3 or something like that. This problem is weird and getting on my nerves. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Ajax to load the grid? if yes, then its probably the cache.

Add this javascript code after you loaded jquery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Also, i see that you have a static method called `GetDisplacementsNotCompensatedByEmployeeID`.

If it is static, this means that the `dataContext` is static as well --- which is not good.
DataContext must be initialized per each request and disposed afterwards.

Comment: I'm using a Kendo UI grid, and the DataSource is ajax yes.   .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Read(read => read.Action("DisplacementsCD_Read", "Request"))
      )

Comment: I initialized a new data context and it worked. Thanks for that warning, because I didn't knew that. :)